# Designing Component React is reusable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building web apps using react and typescript. I have quite similar components and only different api.( example: function onLoadInfoMasterBill() )
How can I write generic components that can be reused?
I just started learning react and typescript recently.

```
 export class UIAirHoubillForm extends UIHoubillForm {
  onLoadInfoMasterBill() {
    let { appContext, pageContext, observer } = this.props;
    let houseBill = observer.getMutableBean();
    let callback = (result: any) => {
      let observer = new MultiBeanObserver(result.data);
      let html = <UIAirMasterBill appContext={appContext} pageContext={pageContext} observer={observer} />;
      pageContext.onAdd('master-bill-detail', `Master Bill ${houseBill.masterBillCode}`, html);
    };
    let restClient = appContext.getServerContext().getRestClient();
    restClient.get(`/logistics/management/air/master-bill/${houseBill.masterBillCode}`, {}, callback);
  }

  renderMasterCodeField(houseBill: any) {
    let { FormGroup } = widget.layout;
    let { BBReference } = widget.input;
    let html = (
      <FormGroup>
        <label>Master Bill Code</label>
        <BBReference bean={houseBill} field={'masterBillCode'} onInfo={() => this.onLoadInfoMasterBill()} />
      </FormGroup>
    );
    return html;
  }
}
```

```
  export class UISeaHoubillForm extends UIHoubillForm {
  onLoadInfoMasterBill() {
    let { appContext, pageContext, observer } = this.props;
    let houseBill = observer.getMutableBean();
    let callback = (result: any) => {
      let observer = new MultiBeanObserver(result.data);
      let html = <UISeaMasterBill appContext={appContext} pageContext={pageContext} observer={observer} />;
      pageContext.onAdd('master-bill-detail', `Master Bill ${houseBill.masterBillCode}`, html);
    };
    let restClient = appContext.getServerContext().getRestClient();
    restClient.get(`/logistics/management/sea/master-bill/${houseBill.masterBillCode}`, {}, callback);
  }

  renderMasterCodeField(houseBill: any) {
    let { FormGroup } = widget.layout;
    let { BBReference } = widget.input;
    let html = (
      <FormGroup>
        <label>Master Bill Code</label>
        <BBReference bean={houseBill} field={'masterBillCode'} onInfo={() => this.onLoadInfoMasterBill()} />
      </FormGroup>
    );
    return html;
  }
}
```

Comment: pass api url as props then on `componentDidMount()` read url and call the api request.

Comment: The code in either snippet isn't a react component, and unless my eyes fail me, it looks like you posted the same code twice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a generic js function

You can pass the api as parameter

```
onLoadInfoMasterBill('/logistics/management/sea/master-bill/') //for sea
onLoadInfoMasterBill('/logistics/management/air/master-bill/') //for air
```

This is how the function will look like

```
onLoadInfoMasterBill(apiParam) {
let { appContext, pageContext, observer } = this.props;
let houseBill = observer.getMutableBean();
let callback = (result: any) => {
  let observer = new MultiBeanObserver(result.data);
  let html = <UIAirMasterBill appContext={appContext} pageContext={pageContext} observer={observer} />;
  pageContext.onAdd('master-bill-detail', `Master Bill ${houseBill.masterBillCode}`, html);
};
let restClient = appContext.getServerContext().getRestClient();
restClient.get(`${apiParam}${houseBill.masterBillCode}`, {}, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign some directory to a component and then check it on `componentDidMount()` like this :

```
<Route
    exact
    path={[
      "/:sea",
      "/:air",
      "/:other",
    ]}
    component={Blog}
  />
```

then `componentDidMount()` should be like this :

```
componentDidMount(){
  let path = this.props.location.pathname;
  ....
  restClient.get(`/logistics/management${path}/master-bill/${houseBill.masterBillCode}`, {}, callback);
}
```